# Cucumber Java- parameterize steps and for each iteration run the next step definitions as well in the desired order

Tags: parameter-passing, cucumber-java

Scenario : Test search for multiple options
Give login to the application
And Navigate to search page
When User Searches with different available search fields
| Search By |
| Team |
| First Name   |
| Designation  |
And Submit the Search request
Then View result details in the Results Grid

Use case:
Login only once, but run the **When -> And -> Then** steps one after another for each of the data table iteration.

I tried with for loop, but And , Then steps are getting executed only once i.e. for Designation parameter.

looking for suggestion if this is feasible.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is just a Background step (login), followed by a scenario outline with your Examples.
See: https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline

Probably will end up looking something like this:

```
Feature: test searching

Background:
  Given User is logged in
  And ...

Scenario outline:
  Given User Searches for <searchfield>
  And submits the request
  Then ...

Examples:
| searchfield |
|    Team     |
| First Name  |
 etc...
```

The example rows can have multiple named columns if you need (see the link).